# Bitlocker PIN rejected after dual-install of Ubuntu with encryption

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, multi-boot, bitlocker

I have a Thinkpad with Windows 10 installed, with Bitlocker setup and previously working. I've just installed Ubuntu along-side Windows, and I enabled the "encrypt my home drive" option during install. I am using grub as a boot manager.

I can boot into and run Ubuntu fine. If I select Windows from the grub menu, I get to the Bitlocker screen as I normally would, but it no longer accepts the PIN? Is there any recovery from this?

**Update**: If I bypass grub, get the regular system boot menu and choose "Windows boot loader" from there, the Bitlocker PIN is accepted.

So, something about accessing the Windows boot loader from grub is not playing nicely with Bitlocker. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Basically, grub isn't a trusted component in the boot chain and doesn't support that, You can either make linux bootable from the windows boot loader or try the experimental grub that made for this purpose. More info here : https://stomp.colorado.edu/blog/blog/2011/12/05/on-dual-booting-tpm-linux-windows-and-bitlocker/