# How to dual boot windows 10 Pro , Ubuntu and bitlocker activated

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, multi-boot, bitlocker

I would like to install Ubuntu 19.04 with a dual boot on Windows 10 Pro laptop (dell). I tried to disabled secure boot as recommended in many forum but I have BitLocker start to complain. I reverse my change and now everything is back. Is there a recent tutorial that explain how to install Ubuntu with a dual boot on Windows 10 Pro with BitLocker activated?

I found that old tutorial from 2013: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/9528.how-to-multiboot-with-bitlocker-tpm-and-a-non-windows-os.aspx Do you think that method 3 is still up-to-date?

Best Regards

Comment: The reason BitLocker complained about SecureBoot being disabled is that it was enabled when BitLocker was initialized.  It isn't actually required, and the way I know this is the fact, Windows 7 supports BitLocker.  The real solution to this problem is to disable BitLocker, install Ubuntu, then enable BitLocker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No guarantees, but below are some notes that could help.

This is an old tutorial but it still seems plausible.
As EasyBCD is now trialware, install it and ensure that it works before starting.
Ramhound's above comment also seems prudent to follow.

A funny note in Method 3 says:
"you will not be able to access the volume encrypted with Bitlocker after
this procedure", so I hope it only means that Ubuntu won't be able to access the
Windows partition.

There are reports that this configuration
[works](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135654/how-to-install-ubuntu-alongside-bitlocker-encrypted-windows10)
and there are reports that say
[it doesn't](https://blog.wirelessmoves.com/2018/03/dual-boot-ubuntu-and-windows-10-bitlocker.html).
Reports of success
([link](https://superuser.com/questions/287071/can-bitlocker-be-used-in-a-dual-boot-system-with-windows-on-one-drive-linux-on))
are more frequent for the case of both OS being on different drives.
It is also
[reported](https://superuser.com/questions/1094570/bitlocker-pin-rejected-after-dual-install-of-ubuntu-with-encryption)
that bitlocked Windows cannot be started from grub, so you need to boot both
OS through the UEFI bootloader (the Ubuntu installer should do that automatically,
but be vigilant when installing).

If you decide to try, I would suggest to generate first a BitLocker recovery key
on a USB device and a Windows 10 recovery USB.
Take good backups of your data and perhaps also an image backup of the disk,
just in case.

Ubuntu is
[reported](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot)
as working fine with secure boot, but you would not be able to
install kernel drivers that are not in the repository.

Comment: I  was not able to install BitLocker without turn it off. Now everything works fine, I have both installed. Then I wanted to turn BitLOcker On again but then I got an error :

"the path specified in the boot configuration data (bcd) for a bitlocker drive encryption integrity-protected application is incorrect"

Is it even possible to reactivate BitLocker after Ubuntu dual instalation ?
Thank you very much

Comment: Your problem might be the same as in this Microsoft [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929834/error-message-when-you-try-to-run-the-bitlocker-drive-encryption-progr).

Comment: I try to follow instructions  in your link but it did not work. I still have the same error.

Comment: See [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1015677/settings-for-boot-configuration-data-bcd-to-install-bitlocker-on-win-10) where the same problem was apparently solved. The non-accepted answer is based on the same Microsoft article, but the accepted answer requires some fiddling.